# Fetch nested JSON value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am trying to extract data from json and display in ionic application
I tried to extract the Price and Name of Indivisualservice and succeeded,but struck when I tried to fetch HalfservName and HalfPrepareprice

Data:

```
 {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59bba8696d8e3"),
            "username" : "tt@gmail.com",
            "service_offered" : {
                "IndivisualService" : [ 
                    {
                        "Price" : "111",
                        "Name" : "catering",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59bba9046d62535d77e548e6")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "Price" : "1111",
                        "Name" : "delivery",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59bba9046d62535d77e548e5")
                    }
                ],
                "half_service" : {
                    "HalfservType" : {
                        "HalfservName" : [ 
                            "halfPrepare1", 
                            "halfPrepare2", 
                            "halfPrepare3"
                        ],
                        "HalfPrepareprice" : 1000
                    }
                }
            },
            "city" : "ttt" }
```

controller:

```
$scope.details=response.data;
```

view:

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="servicesoffered in details">
    <span ng-show='servicesoffered.IndivisualService.length > 0'>
                <span>Indivisual Service</span>
        <ul>
            <li ng-show='servicesoffered.IndivisualService.length > 0' ng-repeat="IndiService in servicesoffered.IndivisualService">
                <a>Service: {{IndiService.Name}}</a>
                <a>Price: {{IndiService.Price}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

tried to fetch HalfservName and HalfPrepareprice but failed.
could anyone help to fetch HalfservName and HalfPrepareprice

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="servicesoffered in details">
    <span ng-show='servicesoffered.half_service.HalfservType.HalfservName.length > 0'>
                <span>Half Service</span>
        <ul>
            <li 
                ng-repeat="halfServiceoffered in servicesoffered
.half_service.HalfservType">
                <a>Service: {{halfServiceoffered.HalfservName}}</a>
               </li>
        </ul>
    </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not json, its BJSON.

Comment: Seems ok. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: I am trying to fetch HalfservName array elements and HalfPrepareprice  expected output -   HalfservName : halfPrepare1, halfPrepare2, halfPrepare3   HalfPrepareprice: 1000

Answer (score 0):

`HalfservType` is an object. But you probably wanna iterate over the `HalfservName` array. So here is the updated code:

```
<li ng-repeat="halfServiceName in servicesoffered.half_service.HalfservType.HalfservName">
   <a>Service: {{halfServiceName}}</a>
</li>
```